# How to write a unit test for a DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest controller method with MockMvc?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

code like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload/{resource}",method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Object uploadfileUpload(@PathVariable("resource") String resource,DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse resp,MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    ......
}
```

in the code:

```
this.mockMvc.perform(mockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder)
```

only can post a `MultipartHttpServletRequest`,because `mockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder  implements MultipartHttpServletRequest`.  `MultipartHttpServletRequest` is a interface.

How can I create a `DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest`  class object an then in the `mockMvc` post the request to complete my unit test?

Comment: By starting to read tutorials; and experimenting. Not by just dropping your requirements here and expecting other people to do that for you. You are welcome to ask specific questions like "here is code of mine, and it doesn't work here and there ..."

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test
public void testUploadARA3() throws Exception {
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(
            "C:/test_42873.xlsm");
    MockMultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile(
            "test_42873.xlsm", file);
    MockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder mockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder = (MockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder) fileUpload(
            "/upload/{resource}", "ARA").accept(MediaType.ALL);
    mockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder.file(multipartFile);
    //mockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder.content("whatever");

    MockHttpServletRequest request;
    MvcResult response =   this.mockMvc.perform(mockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder).andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();
    System.out.println(response.getResponse().getContentAsString());

}
```

my test code doesn't enter uploadfileUpload methord.

Comment: this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();